# How can I make it give me the desired output? I was given this Python 3.11 exercise, but I can't seem to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.11

> **Malware Analysis**
>
> Your company is analyzing malware which targets numerical record
> files.
>
> The malware uses a sliding window over the array of numbers in a file,
> and tries to match the following pattern:
>
> `Tl, -, -, X, -, -, -, Tr`
>
> The entire window is moved so that 'X' passes through all the values
> and is compared to the numbers at the 'Tl' and 'Tr' locations, which
> are positioned at a constant offset to 'X'.
>
> The malware has the following rules:
>
> - If the value at the 'TI' or 'Tr' position of the pattern is bigger or
>   equal to the value at the 'X' position, the malware replaces the value
>   at 'X' with 0.
> - If the value at the 'TI' or 'Tr' offset is out of
>   bounds, then the value at 'X' is only compared to the other existing
>   value.
> - The record is processed in two stages: first, all the
>   positions that should be set to 0 are located, using the original
>   values for comparison. Only after all positions have been identified
>   do they get set to 0.
>
> following: the are file record a in values the if example:
>
> `[1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3]`
>
> The expected values after the malware runs are:
>
> `[1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0]`
>
> In this example, both '2's, the '4' and the last '3' were replaced by
> 0.
>
> Implement the simulate function so that the malware behavior is
> replicated for further study.

```
def simulate(entries):
    result = entries.copy()

    for i in range(len(entries)):
        if i >= 2:
            X = entries[i]
            Tl = entries[i - 2]
            if Tl >= X:
                result[i] = 0

        if i <= len(entries) - 4:
            X = entries[i]
            Tr = entries[i + 3]
            if Tr >= X:
                result[i] = 0

    return result

# Test the function with the provided example
records = [1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3]
result = simulate(records)
print(result)
# Expected output: [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0]
```

How can I make it give me the desired output? I was given this Python 3.11 exercise, but I can't seem to solve it.

Comment: The Tl index is i - 3, not i - 2.   Likewise, i + 4, not i + 3 for the right.

Comment: Is "following: the are file record a in values the if example:" really in the instructions? It makes no sense at all to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have the algorithm right but you made a error in the offsets to apply.
The pattern is `Tl, -, -, X, -, -, -, Tr`, which means that `Tl` is at offset `i-3` and not `i-2` (same for `Tr` at `i+4`).

Such exercices are a good opportunity to work on your debugging skill:

- use the infamous `print()` function for displaying your state at each loop and the values used in your decision tree

```py
    tl_offest = i - 3
    tl_is_bigger = tl_offset >= 0 and entries[i] <= entries[tl_offset]
    print(f"i={i} => Tl is at {tl_offest} -> {tl_is_bigger}")
    if tl_is_bigger: ....
```

- use a debugger like pdb or any debugger integrated in your IDE
- use unit test (even better) by breaking down your code into functions and testing them

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation:

```
def simulate(entries):
    result = []
    for i, x in enumerate(entries):
        if i < 3: 
            tl = 0
        else:
            tl = entries[i-3]
        try:
            tr = entries[i+4]
        except IndexError:
            tr = 0
        #print("tl: {}, X: {}, tr: {}".format(tl, x, tr))
        if tl >= x or tr >= x:
            result.append(0)
        else:
            result.append(x)
    return result
print(simulate(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer! It would be helpful if you'd [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) the python code in your question using a code block. Also, some additional explanation would be helpful to better understand your solution.